# Crashing trying to warp map files?

Tags: coordinate-system, format

I have been trying to warp ECW and Ozfx3 map formats to GeoTiff format.  I have navigated to `Raster>Projections>Warp(reproject)` I have then selected the file to warp the output that I want and the process starts but each time the process fails within 5  seconds with the dialogue  "The process crashed some time after starting successfully".

Comment: What tool are you using to attempt to warp the rasters?

Comment: have you tried using `gdalwarp` from the shell?

Answer (score 1):

Warping is generally done to change coordinate systems or re-sample an image, so I'm not sure if warping is the correct function you are seeking.

If your intention is to convert an ECW file to a Tiff then I think you should be able to use the [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) utility, with a command like:

```
gdal_translate -of GTIFF "input.ecw" "output.tif"
```